# HTPP request Ajax converted to Laravel for an external api

Tags: laravel, api, http

i will try to a bulk data send to another domain via api that will created at controller in laravel project

my function

```
public function test_prod_insert()
    {
       $usrl= url('/public/wheel_images/rohana_imgs');
        $users = DB::table('products')->select('id','title','sku','image1')->skip(0)->take(2)->get();
        echo"<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='https://trk.mtrl.me/tracking.js?token=**********'></script>";

        foreach($users as $data){
    echo"<script>
        var model = {
  'time': 1518004715732,
  'token': '***************',
  'platform': 'laravel',
  'pluginVersion': '1.1.0',
  'params': {
    'categories': [
      '2'
    ],
    'id': '<?= $data->id ?>',
    'sku': '<?= $data->sku ?>',
    'imageUrl': '<?= $usrl ?>/<?= $data->image1 ?>',
    'name': '<?= $data->title ?>',
    'price': '',
    'url': '',
    'options': [

    ]
  }
};

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(model),
    url: 'https://trk.mtrl.me/product',
    contentType: 'application/json'
}).done(function(res) {       
    console.log('res', res);
    // Do something with the result :)
});
</script>";
}
    }
```

now i converted to Laravel  use Guzzle but how i failed to send these data in laravel show 400 error

in larevel

```
 public function test_prod_insert()
        {
    echo"<script type='text/javascript' src='https://trk.mtrl.me/tracking.js?token=*********'></script>";
            $client = new Client();
            $res = $client->request('POST', 'https://trk.mtrl.me/product', [
      'form_params' => [
      'time'=> 1518004715732,
      'token'=> '*********',
      'platform'=> 'laravel',
      'pluginVersion'=> '1.1.0',
                ]
            ]);
            echo $res->getStatusCode();
            // 200
            echo $res->getHeader('content-type');
            // 'application/json; charset=utf8'
            echo $res->getBody();
            // {"type":"User"...'
    }
```

how i send id,sku,imgeurl... in laravel please help i am new in api and lar

Comment: You shoud set the headers for client.   $headers = [
            'content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded,
            'accept' => 'application/json, text/plain, */*'
        ];
        $client = new Client([
            'headers' => $headers
        ]);

Comment: @berkaykılıç how add loop in this section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove the script and send data to body

```
  $client = new Client();
  $param=[
    "id"=> "91",
    "sku"=> "CM01-R",
    "imageUrl"=> "http://shop-tavan.customerboard.co/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/91.jpg",
    "name"=> "Rare unique blue shirt",
    "price"=> 23.65,
    "url"=> "http://shop-tavan.customerboard.co/product/rare-unique-blue-shirt/"
       ];
 $time = Carbon::now()->timestamp;
          $body=[
                "time"=>$time,
                "token"=> "***********",
                "platform"=>"Laravel",
                "pluginVersion"=> "1.1.0",
                "params"=>$param
              ];

$result=$client->request('POST', 'https://trk.mtrl.me/product', ['body'=>json_encode($body)]);
 echo $result->getStatusCode();
```

i will encode the json data send body part